# Change file name in Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created a class called Equation and then wanted to rename it to Problem. I changed the name in the interface (`@interface Problem : NSObject`) and the name in the implementation file (`#import "Problem.h"` and `@implementation Problem`). I also changed the actual file name. I'm getting this error: `Class 'Problem' defined without specifying a base class` and this warning: `Cannot find interface declaration for 'Problem'`. I ended up deleting and creating the class again, and it worked fine. Is there an easy way to rename files in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click the class name, you can choose refactor-rename.  XCode isn't perfect at this, but it usually works.

[image]

Be careful with things your rename and invoke via reflection as they probably won't be picked up by XCode in the name change.

Answer (score 0):

you could just right click on the name of the class (i.e. Equation in your case) and click refactor->rename.
The refactor utility automatically change class name, file name and imports.